# Rails + Cucumber + Capybara: Matching exact link text

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Cucumber is complaining that I have an ambiguous match for when I tell it to click a link: `Ambiguous match, found 4 elements matching link "Spirits" (Capybara::Ambiguous)`. So I am trying to match the "Spirits" link exactly.

I looked through this: https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#exactness and found the `exact: true` option so I changed my code from:

```
When(/I click on the (.*) link/) do |link_name|
  click_link(link_name)
end
```

to:

```
When(/I click on the (.*) link/) do |link_name|
  click_link(link_name, exact: true)
end
```

But now it's complaining with `wrong number of arguments (2 for 1) (ArgumentError)`. I'm on Rails 3.2.13, capybara (2.0.3), cucumber (1.2.3). Anyone know why there is an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Capybara version is not the latest.

`exact` method added in 2.1.0. https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/master/History.md

You need to upgrade the gem.